# Dynamic page element reference of iframe is no longer attached to the DOM

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem to management the iframes in dynamic page
I have a tableview in one iframe when I double-click on row, it's create a new div with iframe you can see the toggle to this iframe in intructions driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameProduct), after collect data from this frame,  I want to continue traverse table rows, but at the final of loop I try to toogle the tableview iframe with driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframes.ElementAt(1)) and then i have an exception **Dynamic page element reference of iframe is no longer attached to the DOM**

I cannot toggle from one frame to other frame.

```
        ICollection<IWebElement> iframes = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe"));            
        // Table frame
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframes.ElementAt(1));
        
        element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//html"));

        string? paths = @"//table[starts-with(@id, 'tableview')]";
        ICollection<IWebElement> tableview = element.FindElements(By.XPath(paths));

        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        
        foreach (IWebElement elements in tableview) { 

            builder.DoubleClick(elements).Build().Perform();

            // result data frame
            driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();

            ICollection<IWebElement> cc = TabPanelCenter.FindElements(By.XPath("./child::*"));

            var product = driver.FindElement(By.Id(cc.Last().GetAttribute("id")));              

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            var  frameProduct = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable (product.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe"))));

            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameProduct);

            var registration = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblRegistrationDate-inputEl"));

            Console.WriteLine(registration.Text);
           
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframes.ElementAt(1)); // Exception/Error element reference of iframe is no longer attached to the DOM

        }

<div id="TabPanelCenter-body" data-ref="body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default x-noborder-trbl" role="presentation" style="width: 1920px; left: 0px; top: 36px; height: 169px;">
    <div
        class="x-panel x-tabpanel-child x-panel-default x-hidden-offsets"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-hidden="true"
        aria-disabled="false"
        aria-labelledby="tab-1013"
        aria-expanded="false"
        id="Home"
        style="margin: 0px; width: 1284px; height: 778px;"
    >
        <div id="Home-bodyWrap" data-ref="bodyWrap" class="x-panel-bodyWrap" role="presentation">
            <div id="Home-body" data-ref="body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default x-noborder-trbl" role="presentation" style="width: 1284px; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 778px;">
                <iframe
                    class="x-component x-fit-item x-component-default"
                    id="component-1015"
                    name="Home_IFrame"
                    src="/Private/Intranet/Inicio.aspx?_dc=1674059085974"
                    style="margin: 0px; width: 1284px; height: 778px;"
                    frameborder="0"
                ></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div
        class="x-panel x-tabpanel-child x-panel-default x-closable x-panel-closable x-panel-default-closable x-hidden-offsets"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-hidden="true"
        aria-disabled="false"
        aria-labelledby="tab-1016"
        id="Products"
        aria-expanded="false"
        style="margin: 0px; width: 1284px; height: 778px;"
    >
        <div id="Products-bodyWrap" data-ref="bodyWrap" class="x-panel-bodyWrap" role="presentation">
            <div
                id="Products-body"
                data-ref="body"
                class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-closable x-panel-body-closable x-panel-body-default-closable x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default-closable x-noborder-trbl"
                role="presentation"
                style="width: 1284px; height: 778px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"
            >
                **
                <iframe
                    class="x-component x-fit-item x-component-default"
                    id="component-1018"
                    name="Products_IFrame"
                    src="/Private/Intranet/Products/ProductsList.aspx?_dc=1674059096599"
                    style="margin: 0px; width: 1284px; height: 778px;"
                    frameborder="0"
                >
                </iframe>
                **
            </div>
        </div>
        <div
            class="x-component x-border-box x-mask x-component-default"
            role="progressbar"
            aria-hidden="true"
            aria-disabled="false"
            id="loadmask-1017"
            tabindex="0"
            data-componentid="loadmask-1017"
            style="display: none;"
            aria-valuetext="Loading Products..."
        >
            <div id="loadmask-1017-msgWrapEl" data-ref="msgWrapEl" class="x-mask-msg" role="presentation" style="right: auto; left: 576px; top: 361px;">
                <div id="loadmask-1017-msgEl" data-ref="msgEl" class="x-mask-loading x-mask-msg-inner" role="presentation">
                    <div id="loadmask-1017-msgTextEl" data-ref="msgTextEl" class="x-mask-msg-text" role="presentation">Loading Products...</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div
        class="x-panel x-tabpanel-child x-panel-default x-closable x-panel-closable x-panel-default-closable"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-hidden="false"
        aria-disabled="false"
        aria-labelledby="tab-1019"
        id="Edit_product434"
        aria-expanded="true"
        style="margin: 0px; width: 1920px; height: 169px;"
    >
        <div id="Edit_product434-bodyWrap" data-ref="bodyWrap" class="x-panel-bodyWrap" role="presentation">
            <div
                id="Edit_product434-body"
                data-ref="body"
                class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-closable x-panel-body-closable x-panel-body-default-closable x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default-closable x-noborder-trbl"
                role="presentation"
                style="width: 1920px; height: 169px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"
            >
                **
                <iframe
                    class="x-component x-fit-item x-component-default"
                    id="component-1021"
                    name="Edit_product434_IFrame"
                    src="/Private/Intranet/Products/ProductsForm.aspx?Id=434&amp;TabId=Products&amp;_dc=1674059103654"
                    style="margin: 0px; width: 1920px; height: 169px;"
                    frameborder="0"
                >
                </iframe>
                **
            </div>
        </div>
        <div
            class="x-component x-border-box x-mask x-component-default"
            role="progressbar"
            aria-hidden="true"
            aria-disabled="false"
            id="loadmask-1020"
            tabindex="0"
            data-componentid="loadmask-1020"
            style="display: none;"
            aria-valuetext="Loading Edit product..."
        >
            <div id="loadmask-1020-msgWrapEl" data-ref="msgWrapEl" class="x-mask-msg" role="presentation" style="right: auto; left: 567px; top: 361px;">
                <div id="loadmask-1020-msgEl" data-ref="msgEl" class="x-mask-loading x-mask-msg-inner" role="presentation">
                    <div id="loadmask-1020-msgTextEl" data-ref="msgTextEl" class="x-mask-msg-text" role="presentation">Loading Edit product...</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change what? Toggle multiple iFrames? Change the src for an iFrame?

Comment: Using the expected condition of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt​ may help.  (It'll take some time for the iframe to update... probably a very small amount of time, but you'd still want to use a webdriverwait)

Comment: At which line do you see the error? Update the question with the relevant text based HTML and the complete error.

Comment: Hi, I update the post, I hope that the post will be clearly

Comment: pcalkins frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt​  work's for me. Thank You